# Can't copy multiple lines into command-line python

Tags: python, linux

Sometimes, when developing python code, I open a script in gedit and copy chunks of code into the python command line on Linux.  This used to work just fine.  For example, here are two commands which I copied together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Today, however, I am getting the following error when I try to copy and execute multiple lines together:

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

This did not used to happen.  Another difference is that my commands are highlighted white when I paste them into python.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.  Any idea why I can't execute multiple lines together?

Comment: Did you used to be running your interactive shell within an IDE (or a different IDE, if you're still using one)? Some fancier interactive shells will split up your inputs and run one line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like it has something to do with "bracketed paste mode", especially with that highlighting going on. From a distance I can't tell what or how, though. Possibly related to this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue42819 .

Comment: Thanks. This seems to have been the issue. The page github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193 suggested the workaround command: 'echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc'. This resolved the problem and gave me the same python behavior as before, where I can copy chunks of code into the python terminal. However, one page (https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste) suggested that bracketed paste mode is safer when copying unknown commands, so maybe I shouldn't turn it off? Does anyone know? I'm on python 3.8.5, and it sounds this may be fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to run code in the Python shell, you can only run one line of code (more specifically, one statement) at a time. You would have to execute each `import` statement individually.

Comment: Hmm, this behavior is new to me. It seems like a change was made regarding "bracketed paste mode", which is mentioned in the answer that I accepted.